# Why my slideshow freezing on IE?

Tags: javascript, joomla, slideshow, jcarousel, freeze

I have a news slideshow that was built in JavaScript for Joomla.  It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and etc.  However, after two news segments in Internet Explorer it freezes for a long time.  Here is a link to the site: [www.urbanclaim.com](http://www.urbanclaim.com)

How can I stop the delay and get this working correctly and efficiently in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined
```

It worked on IE6 when i removed these lines:

```
this.handles.removeClass('active');
currentHandle.addClass('active');
```

Comment: hey, do you think that this fix can works also on next version of IE? cause we are attending IE10..

Comment: thank you man! it works fine also on IE 8 and 9 !  You can tell me also why IE have this problem with these lines? on web i read that it depens to the class names..but i don't know about that..  thanks.

Comment: The problem because currentHandle is not defined, the problem is not IE problem, it is in your code, so I hope the fix will work in all browsers.